# TTS on iOS 16 (AVFoundation) works in simulator but not on my iPhone

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation, text-to-speech

I am working on a app atm but noticed that TTS does not seem to be working on my physical iPhone.
It works fine in the simulator but once I load it onto my iPhone I can't hear any voice anymore. Do you have any idea why it could be?

I have a sample code here which works as described above.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Test") {
                let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello")
                utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-UK")
                utterance.rate = 0.5
                

                synthesizer.speak(utterance)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I looked online but found nothing because it seems that if someone has had problems with the tts it was there in general.

**On my physical phone, I get the following error messages in Xcode:**

2023-05-07 06:34:20.205986+0200 testTTS[920:34896] [catalog] Unable to list voice folder
2023-05-07 06:34:20.226466+0200 testTTS[920:34896] [catalog] Unable to list voice folder
2023-05-07 06:34:20.230243+0200 testTTS[920:34896] [catalog] Unable to list voice folder
2023-05-07 06:34:20.245084+0200 testTTS[920:34896] [catalog] Unable to list voice folder
2023-05-07 06:34:20.291238+0200 testTTS[920:34896] [catalog] Query for com.apple.MobileAsset.VoiceServices.VoiceResources failed: 2
2023-05-07 06:34:20.307714+0200 testTTS[920:34919] [AXTTSCommon] MauiVocalizer: 11006 (Can't compile rule): regularExpression=\Oviedo(?=, (\x1b\pause=\d+\)?Florida)\b, message=unrecognized character follows , characterPosition=1
2023-05-07 06:34:20.309944+0200 testTTS[920:34919] [AXTTSCommon] MauiVocalizer: 16038 (Resource load failed): component=ttt/re, uri=, contentType=application/x-vocalizer-rettt+text, lhError=88602000
2023-05-07 06:34:20.309963+0200 testTTS[920:34919] [AXTTSCommon] Error loading rules: 2147483648

**When running the app in the simulator I only get these errors:**

2023-05-07 06:44:25.798770+0200 testTTS[77483:2075261] [asset] Failed to get sandbox extensions
2023-05-07 06:44:25.838040+0200 testTTS[77483:2075261] [catalog] Unable to list voice folder
2023-05-07 06:44:25.866640+0200 testTTS[77483:2075261] [catalog] Unable to list voice folder
2023-05-07 06:44:25.869643+0200 testTTS[77483:2075261] [catalog] Unable to list voice folder
2023-05-07 06:44:25.882157+0200 testTTS[77483:2075261] [catalog] Unable to list voice folder
2023-05-07 06:44:25.900457+0200 testTTS[77483:2075257] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000271d220> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

Comment: OK, solved it. My phone was on mute.